# William Fractals without Plotshape offset

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to remove the offset from the plotshape, in other words how would we need to modify the (upFractal) condition so I can use plotshape without any offset to make it work as if the offset (-6) was there, even if it is delayed?

````
//@version=5
indicator("Williams Fractals", shorttitle="Fractals", format=format.price, precision=0, overlay=true)
// Define "n" as the number of periods and keep a minimum value of 2 for error handling.
n = input.int(title="Periods", defval=6, minval=2)


// UpFractal
bool upflagDownFrontier = true
bool upflagUpFrontier0 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier1 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier2 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier3 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier4 = true

for i = 1 to n
    upflagDownFrontier := upflagDownFrontier and (high[n-i] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier0 := upflagUpFrontier0 and (high[n+i] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier1 := upflagUpFrontier1 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 1] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier2 := upflagUpFrontier2 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 2] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier3 := upflagUpFrontier3 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= high[n] and high[n+3] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 3] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier4 := upflagUpFrontier4 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= high[n] and high[n+3] <= high[n] and high[n+4] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 4] < high[n])
flagUpFrontier = upflagUpFrontier0 or upflagUpFrontier1 or upflagUpFrontier2 or upflagUpFrontier3 or upflagUpFrontier4

upFractal = (upflagDownFrontier and flagUpFrontier)

plotshape(upFractal) //this doens't put the plotshape in the right position, would it be a way to put it without using offset? if you add offset -6 it would be. ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `plotshape()`, you can use a `label` instead.

```
if (upFractal)
    label.new(bar_index-6, high, "W", yloc = yloc.abovebar)
```

The 6 bar delay will always be there.

Comment: Thank you Vituvius for your help! Would it be any way to modify the (upFractal) condition so I can use plotshape without the offset, even if it is with delay? How would you do that please?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You need the offset because of the delay.

Comment: It has to be possible somehow, maybe with the loop function that looks back, we shall see . Thanks Vituvius for your help anyway.

Comment: It is not. You must understand how fractals and `plotshape()` work first.

Comment: Thanks vituvius, after 2 years using plotshapes I think I know how they work, the offset too, and the delay on the fractals. It has to be a way whem the condition is met, to go i bar-indexes back and place it on the right place without usimg a plotshape offset

Comment: Sorry but that's not how `plotshape()`s work. If you want to plot something on a bar that is not the current bar, you MUST use the `offset` argument.

Comment: Or you can offset the condition and use the plotshape() without any offset, which is what I am after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248931/discussion-between-shuman-rotula-and-vitruvius).